# Is the Standard Lightning Compo "Activities" programatically usable in custom Components or on visualforce pages?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

In the Lightning App Builder used to arrange a Flexipage, the topmost Standard Components on the leftside panel is called Activities.

Is this Component also available (or exposed) and usable in a Lightning Container on a Visualforce Page or inside other Custom Lightning Components?

[image]

What I've tried so far is to look at `/auradocs/reference.app` - but was not able to identify it there:

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, since Activities does not have Standard Controller in Classic View, a Lightning Component cannot be used to reference Activities on a Classic page (you'd need to specify either Task or Event, etc). I can't speak to it's use on other Lightning Pages.